# Unable to plot using igraph, with cairo and py3cairo

Tags: python, eclipse, homebrew, xcode, pip

So I removed Xcode some time back, finding it more complicated than the intuitive GUI of PyCharm and Eclipse.

In my effort to use `igraph` library for Python 3 however, it requires `cairo` for plots.

While official [link](https://cairographics.org/pycairo/) advises MacPort, since I removed Xcode, I followed [this](https://github.com/pygobject/pycairo/issues/39) link.

With the advice given under the post, I also installed `py2cairo` using `brew install`.

Problem that remains is, python still cannot locate it. 
Quick auto-config nor adding library directories manually under “Preferences -> Pydev -> Interpreters - Python Interpreters” will solve the situation.

[image: Eclipse Preference Setting]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found several links helpful for this topic:

- Manual install->
  https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/wiki/Installation---OSX
- Bit of a tweak (use `cairocffi` instead)
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12072093/python-igraph-plotting-not-available

I actually `brew install`-ed, manual installed, and installed cairocffi.
Was reminded of the boost library that I had to direct IDE to find its path for, but this issue had multiple videos to guide me through.

In an essence, `cairocffi` solved the issue at the end. I can plot without importing anything on the script.

Specified paths are something in the like as followed:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Xcode provides a development environment (compiler, linker, IDE, and so forth) and is somewhat equivalent to the `@Development Tools` package group for RedHat type system, or the `build-essential` package on Debian systems.

MacPorts depends on Xcode, much as `rpmbuild` for RedHat depends on the `@Development Tools` package group. It does not make sense to try to use MacPorts without Xcode installed, just as one would not try to compile software on Linux without the above build or development packages installed.

[Homebrew](https://brew.sh) is an ports or package manager for macOS like MacPorts; Apple never made one so the community wrote [Fink](http://www.finkproject.org) and [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) and [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org), which all do more or less the same job of providing unix software as ports or packages for macOS. FWIW, BSD systems tend to call them ports, and Linux systems packages, regardless the term they make 3rd party packages available for install.

[Git](https://git-scm.com) is version control software that is commonly associated with software development, but could also be [Dracs](http://darcs.net) or [Fossil](https://fossil-scm.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki) or [Mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org).

Comment: yes. sorry about it. I wanted to give some appreciations as all of your answers did help.. but I wasnt able to due to my reps..now I can! awesome!

Answer (score 2):

#### Install the Xcode command line tools if you don’t need a full install of Xcode.

If you need Xcode command line tools without the HUGE Xcode application and environment, the preferred alternative for many developers is to simply install the Xcode command line tools like this:

```
xcode-select --install
```

When you run that command from the Terminal, a macOS software installation pop-up will appear asking you to install the Xcode command line tools. Of course, go ahead and install those.

And when that is done, try `sudo port` again. It should be working as expected.

The Xcode command line tools are basically just the core basics Xcode needs to operate from the command line. It’s the same command line tools you would get from a full Xcode install, but in a much smaller—and in my humble opinion—more reasonable package.

#### Homebrew is—in my humble opinion/experience—the better and more stable macOS package installer; opt for that over MacPorts methods if possible.

If that doesn’t work, I would recommend you undo what you have done, install Xcode again, uninstall pretty much all of the tools you installed with MacPorts and ditch MacPorts as well. Instead I would *highly* recommend installing and using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) instead.

[Homebrew](https://brew.sh) is a package installer/management system for macOS—much like MacPorts—but in my experience it is cleaner, easier to use and understand and much better supported.

In fact, [this answer on Stack Exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30089130) seems to address your requirements of getting `cairo` install in macOS but using Homebrew.

Comment: Thanks Jake. My python is `conda` installed, and I did not like to use other methods but I tried your link with `brew install py2cairo`, and now iI can import on the shell finely. Eclipse still malfunctions. Usually they go together so now Im stuck with a different problem. But I will try to edit the question based on yr feedback, understand it has been difficult with limitation of 1.5 hrs when problems are intermixed.